# Center a group of div's in a div

Tags: html, centering

Is it possible to center a group of divs in one div so it'll look like this?

http://oi49.tinypic.com/1yo2dh.jpg

I wonder if you can do it without using a table.

Right now I got this HTML:

```
<nav class="imagemenu">
    <div id="categories">
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>    
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>         
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
        <div class="cata" onClick="#" style="cursor:pointer;"> <img src="image/placeholder.jpg" /> </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And this CSS:

```
.home-menu {
    width:780px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

#categories {
    width:740px;
    height:340px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#333;
}

.cata {
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.cata {
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

Sizes are still depending but is there a possible option to easily center all the cata's in the categories div?

I tried some options like `overflow` and `text-align:center` from other related questions, and perhaps I used them wrong but they don't work.

Answer (score 16):

You can add `text-align`:

```
#categories {
    […]
    text-align:center;
}
```

and `display: inline-block` and you have to remove the `float` from this CSS rule:

```
.cata{
    […]
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/EdHS9/

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm glad I could help. As a note: The event handler is actually `onclick` instead of `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is possible.**

All you need to do is make the `div` elements `inline-block` so they will respond to `text-align:center` like inline elements.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank youu! I understand now what it does :)

Comment: You didn't actually include a link to a fiddle.